# PHP string - remove character and succeeding three characters

Tags: php, string, substring

I have some text which is similar to the following:

```
blah blah blah £2.50 blah blah blah
```

I would like to remove the price from this line, so it is as follows:

```
blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

Note that "blah" can be many different things, as can the value amount, although it always has a pound sign

I am writing in php, and was thinking I could use a variation of str_ireplace to find the £ sign and then delete that & the following 4 characters.

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: `$fixed = substr($str, 0, strpos('£', $str) . substr($str, strpos('£', $str) + 4))`?

Comment: You havent tried anything have you Jeff.

Comment: What if the price is more/less than 4 characters? You probably want a regex for this. Maybe `£\d+\.\d+` even that will be off if it is < a pound and doesn't have leading 0. Also in your replacement string you actually removed `5` characters, not `4`. If you remove `£2.50` you have 2 whitespaces separating the `blah`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to use regular expression match:

```
$str = "blah blah blah £2.50 blah blah blah";
$result = preg_replace('/£([0-9\.]+) /', '', $str);
echo $result; // "blah blah blah blah blah blah"
```

So this matches `£` followed by any number or decimal point, and replaces them with nothing `''`.

Comment: Ah brilliant, just what I needed, thank you very much for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace("/£[ 0-9.]+/i", "", 'blah blah blah £2.50 blah blah blah');`